# Nixos freeze on full cpu usage or ram usage

Tags: nixos

I use Nixos for few months and I have a problem with freezes.

I'm using i3 as a desktop manager with the following specifications:

`nix-shell -p nix-info --run "nix-info -m"`

```
 - system: `"x86_64-linux"`
 - host os: `Linux 4.19.71, NixOS, 19.09pre192418.e19054ab3cd (Loris)`
 - multi-user?: `yes`
 - sandbox: `yes`
 - version: `nix-env (Nix) 2.3`
 - channels(root): `"nixos-19.09pre192418.e19054ab3cd"`
 - channels(hugo): `""`
 - nixpkgs: `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos`
```

Steps to reproduce are hard to find... But do you have any idea about "CPU/ram load management"?

If you need more information about my config or any other questions don't hesitate